# How can I get past the "install vcredist_x86.exe" issue when upgrading Websphere from v8.5.5.8 after I installed vcredist_x86?

Tags: websphere-8, vcredist

I'm trying to upgrade Websphere 8.5.5.8 to Websphere 8.5.5.23 but it stops with the message that I have to install Microsft Visual C++ Redistributable Package x86 and also x64.

But I installed both of those. I ran the installs as administrator. And yet every time I attempt the upgrade I keep getting this problem.

How do I fix this and successfully upgrade?

I installed the 2 vcredist executables. I expected IBM Installation Manager to allow me to upgrade versions. But I keep getting the vcredist message on the validate the prerequisites screen.

Comment: Did you install the right version, they are not backwards compatible. Did you restart installation manager after? I recall there is some shortcoming if it's installed while IM is running

Comment: also, IHS or WAS Plugin? WAS proper doesn't check/require the VS runtime

Comment: I contacted IBM, and received a response. They had me add a line to config.ini to disable MS VC checking. That worked.